# Query not returning expected result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to sql and I'm running the query below

```
 var Pprofile = "SELECT A.POLICY_PROFILE as POLICY_PROFILE,A.STATUS_CODE1,A.EFF_DT, A.END_EFF_DT,E.OTHER_STRING10,E.DISPLAY_EMPLOYEE FROM  EMPLOYEE E , ASGNMT A " +
    "WHERE E.DISPLAY_EMPLOYEE = A.LD1 AND " + 
"POLICY_PROFILE = 'LOCAL_51' AND A.STATUS_CODE1 = 'A' " +
    " ORDER BY E.DISPLAY_EMPLOYEE, A.EFF_DT ASC";
```

The problem is that is returning all the different "effective dates records" for all the employees as shown in the picture. I only want to get the last  effective date record created for each different user. [query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh84N.pngqUERY)

Please I need help with my query which probably can be written much better, but at end I would like to just get the last effective date record, no all of them.

Thank You!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - and we don't need to see this java stuff or whatever that concatenation is.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int, eff_dt date);
insert into t values
(1,'2017-01-01'),(1,'2017-01-01'),(1,'2017-02-01'),
(2,'2017-01-01');

select t.*
from t
where t.eff_dt = (select max(t1.eff_dt) from t t1 where t1.id = t.id);
```